# Why not apply custom style css?

Tags: vaadin7

In my web project I use Vaadin 7.3.6.

My custom css file is here:

```
myproject\src\main\resources\VAADIN\themes\non.print.component.css
```

In `non.print.component.css`

```
@media print {
.noPrint {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

In my code I use this:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
Button myButton = new Button("My custom button");
myButton.setStyleName("noPrint");
```

But it's not work.
When I print current page, the **myButton**  also print.

Answer (score 1):

Your css file will not be used by the Vaadin UI until you do not declare it or include it in your custom theme. 
The best way is to create your custom theme, then you'll have to :

- Add theme annotation to your UI class -> @Theme("mytheme")
- Create a folder 'myproject\src\main\resources\VAADIN\themes\mytheme'
- Put your css / scss stuff there

Please check basics of theming vaadin7 at : https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/themes/themes-css.html

You do not want to create a theme, two solutions :

- Put the CSS file in the src/main/webapp/VAADIN/* directory and use @StyleSheet("vaadin://style.css").
- Put the css file in the src/main/resources/com/example/demo/ directory and use @StyleSheet("style.css").
  *(credits to Alejandro Duarte in offical Vaadin Forum)*

Regards
Sebastien